# Question:Answer ratio says "NaN" when no questions/answers have been posted

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

In the health stats of proposals that haven't gained any questions or answers, the Question:Answer ratio stat says **NaN**.

[image: Screenshot]

I think it should be changed to something like **N/A**.

Comment: This is completely accurate.  Dividing 0 by 0 produces not-a-number.  Appropriate for a site that's frequented by programmers and a nice touch.

Comment: Should be nullity, not NaN. Transreal math FTW!

Comment: @Hans: StackOverflow is only frequented by programmers, the other sites are focussed on other topics.

Comment: is this about educating yahoos with questions or dumbing down everybody to the same level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It now says "0".  It's less correct, but probably less confusing for the average user.