# How many questions is "NaN%", what SO for Teams is a "Q&A for", and how come is it listed as a network site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, stack-overflow-for-teams

The page with the `https://stackexchange.com/sites` URL, amongst normal sites,
 returns an entry for Stack Overflow for Teams:

[image: SO for Teams stats entry on the /sites page]

If this is intentional, and Stack Overflow for Teams *should* appear there, then there are several obvious issues with it:

1. The subtitle consists only of a "Q&A for" text
2. The category is, ironically, "uncategorized" (which should, arguably, be "Technology")
3. The "percent answered" stat does not account for the division by zero, resulting in `NaN% answered` (seems like the supposedly fixed oversight strikes again, see: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68075/786798), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126673/786798), and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136304/786798))
4. All the stats are obviously pointless and potentially problematic should the information be exposed (as Teams are supposed to be private)
5. The link in the site name also leads to a page for locating the Team instance by its URL slug:

   `https://app.stackoverflowteams.com/teams/locate`

   [image: screenshot of the /teams/locate page]

If it is not intentional, then it should be filtered out from the result set,

just as [it is not returned by the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#page=1&pagesize=100&filter=!1b2xrJ3_*BP_3xOv&run=true) when using the `/sites` endpoint.

Comment: We figured out what caused this and it was a quick fix by re-deploying - we'll have more info about this, maybe tomorrow, but the important thing is that we've got it fixed for now.

Comment: Eagerly awaiting a postmortem, @Catija ^_^

Comment: That `Q&A for` part might be getting the string from a table as `site | topic`, there is no topic for teams, and it is left bank. Also, uncategorized should be left alone - this isn't about technology; what if I used a Teams subscription in my restaurant? or my biochemical laboratory? Also, the *0, 0, NaN%* was fine; it only needed some polishing, such as "no stat from private sources." Cont:

Comment: Cont: *The link in the site name also leads to a page for locating the Team instance by its URL slug: app.stackoverflowteams.com/teams/locate* So, what's the issue? There is no such thing as `*.stackexchange.com` for teams, thus it is totally valid. The only issue is that Teams is a service/product rather than a website, so it should be excluded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry about that, should be all fixed now.

We were trying out a new way to deploy the code for [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) to production. Due to an oversight on my end, plus really unfortunate timing, that deployment picked up a bad commit from the `master` branch (which *just* slipped through our test automation - another freak coincidence).

We're putting a few safeguards in place to prevent this from happening again, such as a Slack-based andon cord allowing all developers to immediately stop all production deployments.